# Ipod Classic 160GB shuffle issue

Tags: ipod-classic

I just bought one of the last Ipod classics and for some reason when its in shuffle mode (songs - artists or playlists), it shuffles to the next track in the middle of the current song. odd? is there a solution?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could be drive or file damage.

I had something similar happen on my old classic. The 'fix' was to wipe & restore - which took a long time [24h maybe], but worked.

One thing I've noticed about the classic with the slide-lock switch, don't attempt to sync with it locked.